# FieldError for a collection is not binding in JSP page

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I am validating the `@ElementCollection` with java validation.

```
private SortedSet< @Pattern(regexp = "[0-9]{2,3}", message = "Only numbers allowed")
           String> dummyList = new TreeSet<>();
```

In JSP page spring bind tag is not able to bind the error.

```
 <spring:bind path="obj.dummyList">
               <div>
                    <!--code--->
                    <form:errors path="dummyList" class="control-label form-error"/>
                </div>
</spring:bind>
```

But when the path is replaced with `*` in the errors tag the error is shown on page

Upon inspecting the BindingResult, found that field name is set to `dummyList[]` instead of `dummyList`.

Please suggest a way to make binding work in the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appending `*` to the field name worked.

```
<form:errors path="dummyList*" class="control-label form-error"/>
```